# Grep email address from complete file system on Unix Solaris

Tags: regex, unix, grep, solaris, xargs

I would like to extract any email address from complete filesystem of my UNIX SOLARIS.

I can use below for specific domain email

find / -type f|xargs grep -l "/*@.in.domain.com"

Please find sample below.This is for email address which contains "in.domain.com"

But i want to extract list of files which conatins any email address present in file systems.

```
myuser@localhost:/opt/myuser $ find /opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs* -type f|xargs grep -l "/*@in.domain.com"
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack1/config/pack1ConfigP.xml_20151019
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack2/config/pack2ConfigD.xml
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack5/pub/config/pack5ConfigD.xml.1
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack23/config/pack23ConfigP.xml
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack23/config/pack23ConfigQ.xml
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack23/config/pack23ConfigD.xml
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack24/ns/flow/temp/buildCom/flow.xml
/opt/myuser/V9/server/instance1/default/packs/pack66/ns/flow/temp/buildCom/flow.xml
```

Can someone help me which regex I can use. Thanks in advance.

Note: this is for Unix Solaris.

Comment: Please post some of your sample Inputs-Outputs, and any code you may have tried with it.

Comment: I have rephrased my question with sample

Comment: Related: [How to validate an email address using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)